# What should I do when users log out?

Tags: mixpanel

I am setting Mixpanel up, and I found out that if I log in with a user (and `identify` that user), log out and then re-register as a new user, the new user's details overwrite the previously logged in user (presumably when I call `alias`). How can I tell mixpanel that a user has logged out and to reset the identity token (make it anonymous again)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It was released on Mixpanel Javascript version v2.8.0 the `mixpanel.reset()` function, so that's officially what should be called on user logout. See https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-js/issues/67 .

Answer (score 14):

I ran into the same issue, and after some sleuthing I discovered that you can manually clear the mixpanel cookies with `mixpanel.cookie.clear()`.

However, you need to make sure that the mixpanel library has loaded, so I ended up putting it in a stupid timeout:

```
var id = window.setInterval(function() {
  if (mixpanel.cookie && mixpanel.cookie.clear) {
    mixpanel.cookie.clear();
    window.clearInterval(id);
  }
}, 50);
```

And then, since I didn't want to do this on every page, I added a query string parameter onto my logout redirect URL. So after visiting `/logout` it would redirect them to `/home?_ref=logout`, at which point I would clear the mixpanel cookie only if that query string parameter existed.

It was pretty annoying, but it seemed to work.

Comment: For those with a single page app where you may never refresh, be sure to re-initialize immediately after you clear your cookies.

`mixpanel.cookie.clear(); mixpanel.init("GARBAGE");`

Comment: To be 100% sure Mixpanel loaded, you can use the `loaded` option in the `init` where you pass a function for it to run after it loads: `mixpanel.init("YOUR_TOKEN", { "loaded": function() { ... your clear code goes here ... } } );`

Comment: @kevinnuut why do we need to reinitialize again ?

Answer (score 9):

for android 
on logout you can use this `MixpanelAPI.reset()`

Answer (score 4):

1. Call `clearSuperProperties()` to remove any Super Properties in local
   storage.
2. Set `new_distinct_id = UUID.randomUUID().toString());`
3. Call `.identify(new_distinct_id)` and `.getPeople().identify(new_distinct_id)`

This should wipe the device clean for a fresh user that can then register and be aliased to another `distinct_id`.

> The best way to do this with javascript is to delete the cookie. The name of the cookie is `mp_{mixpanel_token_id}_mixpanel`